# Get current URL for paging

Tags: php

So I'm wondering something.

Instead of passing the URL in the function like e.g:

```
paginate('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE topic_id = $id', 'forum/?action=thread&threadid=292', $perPage)
paginate('SELECT * FROM news_comments WHERE news_id = $id', 'index.php?action=comments&id=17', $perPage)
paginate('select * from ?', 'another page', $perPage)
paginate('select * from ?', 'another page', $perPage)
```

I'd want php to figure out the current url/script.
Obviuosly this wont work (well it does work but i mean look at it)

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

forum/?action=thread&threadid=10&page=2&page=3&page=4&page=5&page=6&page=7&page=8&page=9
```

I'd only want the current `$_GET['page']`

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: What is `paginate()`?

Comment: Could you clarify - "if the current page is xxx I want a php function that returns yyy". Can't figure out what you are asking!

Comment: sorry, i did not get you. do you want the first parma `page`?

Comment: You could easily get the last `page` element but I think you'd be better served by finding out why your script is adding to the array, rather than just updating/replacing the element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass in a current_page variable?

```
forum/?action=thread&threadid=10&current_page=5&page=2&page=3&page=4&page=5&page=6&page=7&page=8&page=9
```

Then you could do:

```
$_GET['current_page']
```